# How can I show a modal after failed form validation?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

When using reactive forms in Angular, we usually see in tutorials sync validators and a small `<p>` or `<span>` under the form control with the error. This element has a simple `*ngIf` that controls its display.

Nevertheless, I need to display a modal when an async validator fails. From what I see in ng-bootstrap ang ngx-bootstrap, the modal is opened calling a function, and doesn't exactly listen to changes in the validation (which I can do easily with the `<p>` and `*ngIf`).

Currently, I use a change listener in my form control, which calls the API that validates it. If the API returns invalid, I raise a flag that I included in the sync validators of my form control (hence making the whole form invalid), and open the modal from there too. (Ultimately I'm not using an async validator).

That code smells funny to me.

Is there a better way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: Can you share your code via a stackblitz?

Comment: @NicholasK You're right that code should be added to the question, but it should never rely on an external resource. That's why the inline stack snippet tool exists.

Comment: Please help us to help you. Share with us your code at least on your question please

Comment: @TylerRoper: Kinda delayed response but IMO the inline stack snippet tool doesn't really work well with angular where there are multiple components/templates/modules/routes etc.

Comment: @NicholasK External resources are fine for supplemental information, my primary point is that the question cannot *rely* on it. There has to be enough information in the question itself, be it code or otherwise, that someone can answer it without being required to navigate elsewhere. Reason being, StackOverflow's purpose is to build a repository of knowledge for future readers. If that link goes bad down the road, the question becomes useless.

Comment: @NicholasK that's exactly the reason. I didn't include code because I feel Angular is very "boilerplate-ful" and, as it is split in multiple files it's somewhat difficult to follow. So I decided to explain everything in plain text. At the moment I have kept it as it is due to other pressing matters, but I will upload some code as soon as possible.

Comment: @JDGamboa: As your question currently stands, we can only guess an 'answer' for you. You would need to show some code atleast.

Answer (score 1):

If you already has an async validator attached, you have to use the `statusChanges`  property of FormControl, with the `distinctUntilChanged` pipe to prevent duplication:

```
this.userForm.get('username').statusChanges
  .pipe(distinctUntilChanged())
  .subscribe(status => {
     // if status is invalid, open dialog or whatever yo like
     console.log('Username validation status: '+ status);
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

I like to use the ngx-smart-modal library for this kind of modal housekeeping.

Docs => https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-smart-modal

This library makes it very easy to manage opening/closing/data delivery/customization/etc when it comes to modals.